# PHP - count specific post variables

Tags: php

I am having several input fields with same name (there are several others input fields but this ones are important):

```
<input type=text name=title1 id=title1/>
<input type=text name=title2 id=title2/>
<input type=text name=title3 id=title3/>...
```

How can I count them (just input with name titlex)?

Comment: If you named them all `name="title[]"` instead, `$_POST['title']` would be an array containing all of them. Is that an option?

Comment: Use the name title[] which will result in an array on within php.

Comment: @Wiseguy I have never thought in that direction. I guess I can put it in same array and then count new array.

Answer (score 3):

If you cannot change the HTML, you could iterate, as long as the $_POST is set.
Example:

```
$i = 1;
while (isset($_POST["title".$i])) {
  //handle input
  $i++;
}
```